# Android Activity destroyed when calling ZXing barcode scanner. How to recover?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, mvvmcross

First of all, I'm using, Xamarin with MvvmCross.

In my ViewModel, I'm using the ZXing `MobileBarcodeScanner` class to scan a barcode when the user clicks a button:

```
var scanner = new MobileBarcodeScanner();
var result = await scanner.Scan();
if (result != null)
{
    CodigoProduto = result.Text;
    InternalPesquisarProduto();
}
```

After the scan, I run the `InternalPesquisarProduto` void, that search for data on a remote server, based of course, on the barcode that was read. This method, also display some loading message while the data is fetched:

```
Ui.DisplayLoading("Searching...", "Searching data");
// Code that fetches the data
Ui.DismissLoading();
```

The `Ui` is a property on my ViewModel defined like this:

```
protected IUiInteractor Ui { get; set; }
```

I receive it by dependency injection. Here is the relevant code from the implementation being used in this scenario:

```
public class AndroidUiInteractor : IUiInteractor
{
    private IMvxAndroidCurrentTopActivity _mvxCurrentTopActivity;

    public AndroidUiInteractor(IMvxAndroidCurrentTopActivity mvxCurrentTopActivity)
    {
        _mvxCurrentTopActivity = mvxCurrentTopActivity;
    }

    public void DisplayLoading(string title, string message)
    {
        _mvxCurrentTopActivity.Activity.RunOnUiThread(() =>
        {
            _progressDlg = new ProgressDialog(_mvxCurrentTopActivity.Activity);
            // Configuring the title and the message
            _progressDlg.Show();
        });
    }
}
```

The problem is that when the `scanner.Scan` is called, my caller activity is destroyed, so when I call the `Ui.DisplayLoading`, the `_mvxCurrentTopActivity.Activity` is `null`.

What is most weird about this case, is that I have two Samsungs with Android 5.0 API 21 that I use in my tests, and this problem only happens in one of them, on the other, the activity is not destroyed when calling the `scanner.Scan`.

**Note**: I'm sorry for anything wrong in the code, but because of company policies, I can only access the internet by Terminal Service, and the Ctrl + V is disabled on it.

Comment: Why not first return to the previous Activity before making the `InternalPesquisarProduto` call?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the problem was in the device. After reseting it's configurations it worked properly.

This might not be a definitive solution for everyone that faces that problem, but in my scenario it could be done.